# React: How Does Importing 'react-addons-{addon}' Work?

Tags: reactjs, npm

For example, to import the test utils:

```
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
```

It works, but there is no such module as 'react-addons-test-utils' under node_modules.

And a cursory look at React source code under node_modules reveals that 'react-addons-test-utils' does not exist. In the module root directory there are only react.js and addons.js.

How does this work? What am I missing with my understanding of NPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't work. Sounds like you may have installed the dependency somewhere globally. I am certain it shouldn't work without the actually package.

BTW, react source code does not actually use `react-addons-test-utils`:
https://github.com/facebook/react/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=react-addons-test-utils

Comment: Not sure how I missed it but with NPM 2 it was pulled as a peer dependency.